# cross site cookies

Tags: cookies

Hi I am trying to clear one of my cookies associated with a domain
www.efiglobal.com on a page generated at this location: https://secure.epromo.com
so this is clearing a cookie in domain x from domain y.

I tried to do this doing frames which I can do but it would make
my code convoluted.

I tried to do this using an iframe and had no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post more details of the code you used in the iframe attempt, and we may be able to help.

Comment: So you try to delete a cookie of another domain?

Comment: yeah I am trying to legitimately delete the cookie of another domain.
I am trying to delete a cookie of domain x from a page on domain y.


I have tried lots of ways and the only way I found is
to use old frames which I though was going out of style for some years now.

Answer (score 0):

If the domain where the cookie is from has an url where the user can delete his cookies, like `http://www.efiglobal.com/logout` or `http://www.efiglobal.com/?clearallcookies` you can place an iframe on any site pointing to that url.

But if the first domain has no such url, you can not remove the cookie remotely, since you have no access to any cross domain cookies!